# Set "from" in url on Phonecall Activity In Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, xrm

I´m trying to **call a url to open a phonecall activity** in Microsoft Dynamics CRM by passing "directioncode" and "from" but when I pass the parameter **"from"** with **contact Guid** it doesn't work.

This Works:

```
MyCrmUrl/main.aspx?etc=4210&pagetype=entityrecord&extraqs=?fdirectioncode=1
```

This also works:

```
MyCrmUrl/main.aspx?etn=contact&pagetype=entityrecord&id={5bda9c95-6569-e511-80d3-000c2986cdc5}
```

This don't:

```
 MyCrmUrl/main.aspx?etc=4210&pagetype=entityrecord&extraqs=?fdirectioncode=1&from={5bda9c95-6569-e511-80d3-000c2986cdc5}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extraqs parameter and url encode the following string: fromid=?&fromname=?&fromtype=?
similar to this example:

```
function OpenEmail(recordid, recordtypecode) {
    var params = "pId=" + recordid + "&pName=&pType=" + recordtypecode;
    params += "&partyid=" + recordid + "&partyname=&partytype=" + recordtypecode;
    var url = "/main.aspx?etc=4202&pagetype=entityrecord&extraqs=" + encodeURIComponent(params);
    url = Xrm.Page.context.prependOrgName(url);
    window.open(url);
}
```

found here: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/hardworkdays/archive/2014/01/12/ms-crm-2011-2013-open-new-email-form-with-to-and-regarding-fields-prefilled